# Install django-simple-captcha have some error

Tags: python, django

1. Install Django-simple-captcha via pip: pip install Django-simple-captcha - success
2. Add captcha to the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py - Done!
3. Run python manage.py migrate - have some problem

```
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captchausers'
```

Who can tell me what can I do?

Comment: you did not add comma to separate apps in list captcha, users

Comment: OK, I miss the comma, You save me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I miss a comma. thank @iklinac